# How to copy and paste in Terminal using keyboard?

Tags: command-line

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> prints `^c` in Terminal and does not work. It is same for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (`^v`).
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try CTRL+SHIFT+C and CTRL+SHIFT+V.

Comment: `SHIFT+INSERT` also works.